# Select logs after time in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

In `AWS Athena` I want to filter logs between a certain time. I need to add a check for the time column to the where clause. I tried finding out how to do this, but I cannot find any examples.

I need something like this:

```
SELECT distinct(request_url) FROM "mylogs"."alb_logs"
where request_url like '%app%' and time >= date('2019-01-01')
order by request_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to parse the time using `parse_datetime`. Afterward, you can use compare functions.

```
SELECT distinct(request_url) FROM "mylogs"."alb_logs"
WHERE parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') 
 > parse_datetime('2019-01-01-00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss') 
     AND request_url like '%app%'
order by request_url
```